# VimShellでのウィンドウ移動

Tags: vim

タイトル通りです
VimShellを:splitしてから開くとC-wと矢印でウィンドウ間移動できなくなります。
ウィンドウ間移動するには他の方法が必要なんでしょうか？それとも特殊な設定が必要なんでしょうか？
詳しい方回答お願いします。

Comment: そもそもデフォルトのVimでは、矢印キーでウインドウ間の移動はできないので、`<Left>`, `<Right>`, `<Up>`, `<Down>`に何かしらのマッピングがされているのではないかと思います。差し支えなければvimrcの内容を質問に追記してください。

Comment: vimrcには全くそのような記載はありません

Comment: C-wが表示されていませんでしたので修正しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常、VimShellを開始すると挿入モードになっているので、ノーマルモードの操作である`<C-w>矢印`が使えないということなのだと思います。ですので、VimShellのウインドウで`<Esc>`を押して、ノーマルモードに移行すればそのあとは、ウインドウ間移動の操作ができるはずです。（VimShellのドキュメントを見ましたが、ノーマルモードの`<C-w>`は特に使用されてないようです）

下記のコードをvimrcに追加すれば、`<Esc>`を押さなくてもウインドウ間の移動の操作ができるようになりますのでお試しください。（ただしVimShellの挿入モードの`<C-w>`(単語削除)の操作はできなくなります）

```
autocmd FileType vimshell call s:vimshell_settings()
function! s:vimshell_settings()
  inoremap <buffer><C-w> <Esc><C-w>
endfunction
```